# How to insert link of first child from first child when parent link is (#)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please tell me that how i insert link of first child in parent li.

```
   <li class="parent">
            <a href="#">About</a>
                                <ul>
                   <li class="child">
                        <a href="About.html" title="About">About</a>


                    </li>
                                                                    <li class="child">
                        <a href="service.html" title="Staff">Service</a>


                    </li>
                                                                    <li class="child">
                        <a href="contact.html" title="Testimonials">Contact</a>


                    </li>
```

After Script i want to that result

```
   <li class="parent">
            <a href="About.html">About</a>
                                <ul>
                   <li class="child">
                        <a href="About.html" title="About">About</a>


                    </li>
                                                                    <li 
      class="child">
                        <a href="service.html" title="Staff">Service</a>


                    </li>
             <li class="child">
           <a href="contact.html" title="Testimonials">Contact</a>


                    </li>
```

**Please tell me that how i insert link of first child in parent li. Please check and tell me how to that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `attr` to get/set attribute and use `$(selector).find()` to perform dom element query.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.parent').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('>a').attr('href') === '#') { //requested added cond.
       $(this).find('>a').attr('href', $(this).find('>ul>li:first>a').attr('href'));
    }    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent">
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="child">
    <a href="About.html" title="About">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="child">
    <a href="service.html" title="Staff">Service</a>
    </li>
    <li class="child">
    <a href="contact.html" title="Testimonials">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li class="parent">
  <a href="nochange.html">Service</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="child">
    <a href="service.html" title="Staff">Service</a>
    </li>
    <li class="child">
    <a href="About.html" title="About">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="child">
    <a href="contact.html" title="Testimonials">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer will you please tell me how to do only on (#) link for parent when parent link is not # then it's not changed. Thanks

Comment: @MamunSardar you can include it in the selector

Answer (score 2):

```js
// finds all a with href="#" in .parent
$('.parent > a[href="#"]').each(function(){
  // for each sets href
  $(this).attr('href',
    // gets a`s siblings "ul"s and finds first a in li
    $(this).siblings('ul').find('li > a:first').attr('href')
  )
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent">
  <a href="#">About</a>
 <ul>
  <li class="child">
   <a href="About.html" title="About">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="child">
   <a href="service.html" title="Staff">Service</a>
  </li>
  <li class="child">
   <a href="contact.html" title="Testimonials">Contact</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer but Mamun Sardar just answer me before you minute Sorry. Otherwise this is also awesome. Thanks Again